# Trouble installing pyserial with macports python (python27) on Mac

Tags: python, macos, macports, pyserial

I installed py-serial using macports (on my mac) but it installed python24 instead of using my existing python27.

So if use the python24 that macports py-serial installed then I can import py-serial

```
# /opt/local/bin/python2.4 -c 'import serial'
```

But I cannot import it into python27 using either of these

```
# /opt/local/bin/python2.7 -c 'import serial'
# python -c 'import serial'
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named serial
```

I made sure I have the correct version selected:

```
# port select --set python python27
```

I tried uninstall and reinstall it still gives the same error as above

```
# sudo port uninstall
# port install py-serial
```

I think this is a problem related to my macports/python, not py-serial. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suggest superuser rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: The issue is that code does not work - so it could still be on topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

py-serial is the port for python2.4 for later versions of python use the numbered version e.g.

```
sudo port install py27-serial
```

It is an historical error - originally they thought they should just have one  version of python packages then it was realised that you could have multiple versions of python and that many packages are version dependant.

Comment: That did it. I did not know that I had to use the "pyXX" prefix. Is that a standard format for macports/python?